# How to monitor a text file and parse new lines?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wondering if there is a way to monitor a .txt file without locking it and have the newly appended lines parsed in order to be sent to a database.

I know `FileSystemWatcher` will monitor the txt file without locking it and notify me if a change has occurred. The problem is that it does not tell the lines of data that has been appended. All of the examples I have looked at exclude the part of displaying newly appended lines or doing any processing of the new data. My program has the following structure:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      
  //string line;

  //createWatcher (FileSystemWatcher)
  foreach (string line in getLines(@"C://Documents/log.txt"))
  {
    string teststring = line;         
    string[] parts = line.Split(' ', ',', '-', '>', '[', ']');
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            
    foreach (string h in parts)
    {
      builder.Append(h).Append(" ");
    }

    string result = builder.ToString();
    string cleanedString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result, @"\s+", " ");
    string trimString = cleanedString.Trim();
    trimString = trimString.Remove(trimString.Length - 7);

    //Console.WriteLine(trimString);

    //Process new lines (parse/split)
    //Connect and send to database
  }
}
```

So my objective is to monitor a .txt file without locking it.

1. Read this file for existing data, and wait for appended data.
2. I then want to parse this data and send it to a database.

Does anyone know how to best approach this? or have a good tutorial?

Comment: The reason that you don't see lots of examples of it is because "getting the last line(s) of a text file" is not an easy task, unless the file has a fixed number of bytes per line.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is for the code fired off of the file system watcher to keep track of the `Position` in the stream that's reading the file.  Here's some pseudocode:

```
if(no stored position)
  start at beginning of file
else
{
  streamOfFile.Seek(storedPosition)
  read until end of file
  store stream.Postition
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Servy, I will try this and see what results I get.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done by tracking the length of the file the last time you read it, and then starting from that point next time.  However, there are lots of race conditions around this since you're potentially reading from a file at the same time as the OS is writing.

Isn't your bigger problem that you can't guarantee that the only change to the file is an append?  What happens if I insert a line at the top of the file, or replace the whole thing?

Comment: You are right about that Dan, I guess I never thought of that. It's a very controlled system, so I know for sure that the whole thing will not be replaced by a line or anything of that sort. In any case the FileSystemWatcher should catch the change right? regardless of position?